# Deleting answer by deleting content

Tags: discussion

https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/115940/revisions

Is that an acceptable way to delete your answer when you feel you overthought the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [When is it kosher to delete one's own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216846/238438)

Beyond the "no deleting accepted answers" enforced by the system, there aren't any particular hard and fast rules regarding deleting one's own posts. The usual etiquette mostly boils down to "avoid removing content which may be in some way still useful". It could be that this is the reason the delete button was not utilized in the answer you linked, as editing leaves the comments and edit history visible for all users.

That said, when going the edit route, I would suggest leaving the body intact (or in spoiler tags), prefaced with a warning which explains the reason the answer is no longer favorable. That way casual readers can see for themselves what the fuss is about without having to poke around in the revision history.